# Problem receiving 2 byte numbers with characters on arduino using bluetooth

Tags: c, arduino, bluetooth

I am working on an app that allows me to control my NeoPixel LED Strip through bluetooth. Normal commands are sent as a single char character, whilst slider values for brightness and hue are sent as a two byte integer.

But I am having two problems with my code. The first is that I cannot receive one byte and two data interchangeably on my arduino. Here is my current code:

```
void loop()  { 

  if (BlueTooth.available() >= 1){
    BT_input=(BlueTooth.read());

    if(BT_input == 'n'){
      brightness = 255;
      setRGB();
    }

    if(BT_input == 'f'){
      brightness = 0;
      setRGB();
    }

  }

  if (BlueTooth.available() >= 2){
    unsigned int value1 = BlueTooth.read();
    unsigned int value2 = BlueTooth.read();
    unsigned int real_value = (value2*256) + value1;
    Serial.println(real_value);

    if(real_value >= 1000 && real_value <= 1100){
      brightness = map(real_value, 1000, 1100, 0, 255);
      setRGB();
      delay(10);
    }

    if(real_value >= 2000 && real_value <= 2360){
      hue = map(real_value, 2000, 2360, 0, 360);
      setRGB();
      delay(10);
    }

    if(real_value >= 3000 && real_value <= 3360){
      hue = map(real_value, 3000, 3360, 0, 360);
      colorWipe();
      delay(10);
    }
  }
}
```

When I comment out the first chunk of code that checks for one byte of data I am able to receive values for the incoming two byte massages. But the moment I try to run both things at once, only the one bytes are received and anything over that is ignored.

My second problem is regarding my slider values. When my two byte code does work, it only works perfectly when I tap my finger on the slider. The moment I slide my finger across it, the two byte values received end up growing bigger and bigger till they are too high for my if statements to detect anything. Then if I go back to tapping the slider, values remain in the tens of thousands range.

So I am wondering what could be the issue. I know it has something to do with how I am receiving and differentiating between my data as when I comment out the one byte code, the two byte code works, although not perfectly.

*side note: the serial is set to the right baud rate and all of the pins and objects for both bluetooth and neopixel strip have been set up properly.

Comment: It's a byte stream.  You cannot transfer messages longer than one byte without an extra protocol on top.

Comment: I'm sorry, could you please elaborate, im still very new to arduino and bluetooth.